# Slicers in PivotTables showing incorrect items

Tags: excel, slicers

File at the bottom.

I am trying to create dashboard in Excel 2010 using PivotTables and Slicers.

I am creating 5 different PivotTables from same data source.

The dashboard will have 5 slicers, of which two of them changes each PivotTables and the rest relevant PivotTables.

The slicers of those 3 displaying incorrect data.

At first when Im adding the slicers the items are displaying correctly, but when I change the slicer 1 it gets messed up.

I have tried setting up connections with PivotTables at the end, different layouts of PivotTables, the PivotTables don't retain fields deleted from source.

I want the slicers 3-5 to display only relevant items. 
Slicer 3 from Gender Category (Female & Male), Slicer 4 from University Category (Uni Names), slicer 5 from Custom Category (Custom Questions).

[>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>File to see<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z8ZJjl-9K_kqVts1SaWnQKbcLmIwdd8s/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Did you previously have these values in your dataset?  There is a slicer option that says "Show items deleted from dataset". If you unselect this option, old values will go away.

[image: Screenshot of slicer settings]

Comment: it's new data set, I'm creating it for the first time. The problem is the Gender Category gets data from all categories.

Comment: The problem is that I need to set fixed filter in these Pivots, for example Gender. I do not want to give that option in slicer. So when I change the question it shows items from all categories not just Gender. I need to reselect Gender once again to be showing properly. How can I fix that?

Comment: Are your slicers linked to multiple pivot tables? If you want Gender to be the same across all pivot tables, then you need to link the slicer to all tables

Comment: As above, 2 slicers Question and Answer are linked to all Pivot tables. The rest to one each.